# Convert epoch time in Ruby (Long string)

Tags: ruby

Epoch time with leading 3 zeros is returning an invalid year.

```
Time.at(1520486517000).to_datetime
 => Wed, 19 Apr 50152 19:20:00 +0530
```

After removing ending 3 zeros, it's returning and valid time stamp.

```
Time.at(1520486517).utc.to_datetime
=> Thu, 08 Mar 2018 05:21:57 +0000
```

Is there any way in ruby to churn the epoch time to valid timestamp, when the input has lengthy epoch numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime#strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) with `"%Q"` formatter for parsing milliseconds.

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime 1520486517000.to_s, '%Q'
#⇒ #<DateTime: 2018-03-08T05:21:57+00:00 ((2458186j,19317s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Of course it does. And unlike your first attempt, it indeed saves milliseconds.

Comment: I think both give the similar answer. And I don't know much about the performance. Anyways thanks :)

Comment: You think wrong and I already explained why. Try to compare results when the epoch _indeed has milliseconds_.

Comment: I got it. But in my case, every time I will receive the number leading with 3 zeros. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the following way to handle the long timestamp.

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/85822

```
Time.at(1520486517000/1000).utc.to_datetime
 => Thu, 08 Mar 2018 05:21:57 +0000
```

Comment: This is wrong. One should use `DateTime.strptime` with `%Q` formatter.

Comment: Can you suggest your answer? @mudasobwa

Comment: Integer division results in truncation. Float division results in rounding errors. You have to use `Time.at(1520486517000.quo(1000))` to get the correct result.